# Realm AddOrUpdate an object with a list of objects overrides the later

Tags: ios, swift, list, realm

I have 2 classes:

```
class RealmUser: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var age: Int? = nil
    @objc dynamic var name: String? = nil
}
```

and

```
class Event: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    let participants = List<RealmUser>()
}
```

and let' say that currently in DB I have

- User 1 / 18 years old / "Foo"
- User 2 / 25 years old / "Bar"

Now when I receive an Event from an API which contains a minimal representation of Users such as:

```
{
    event_id: 10,
    name: "Super Event",
    participants: [
        {
            user_id: 1,
            name: "Foo"
        },
        {
            user_id: 2,
            name: "New Bar"
        },
    ]
}
```

So there is no `age`, Realm will override the existing Users instead of merging the data.

What I expected in DB at the end is to have the full User objects updated.

Instead, the variable `age` has been reset to nil as if it wasn't updated but overrided.

I'm calling the function `realm.add(parsedEvents, update: true)`

Comment: Please share the declaration and initialization of `parsedEvents` so we can see exactly what you're passing to Realm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm cannot magically determine that when you add an object with a `nil` field you want it to ignore that field rather than set it to `nil`.

One solution would be to instead use `realm.create(parsedEvents, update: true)` and pass it a Dictionary which is missing the keys that you do not want to update rather than passing it an object.

Comment: It makes sense, but how can I use `create` with an array of objects? It seems like I can only do it object by object.

Comment: The  `add()` overload that takes a sequence is just `for obj in objects { add(obj, update: update) }`, so you just have to do that loop manually (there's no equivalent overload for `create()` as it could sometimes be ambiguous).